# Swift file integration error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, configuration

I am a swift developer and just started working on an Objc project by adding swift code in it.
I'm really blocked with this error here, no matter what i do i still got this error [image]

The file i added is in a submodule and i got this error :

[image]

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Add "ProjectName.Swift.h" header file to Objective C class in which you want communicate with Swift files. That's it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me when you were added your swift file in your objective c code at that time Xcode ask about to add **Bridging-Header** file ? if not then you can add it from new file -> Header File by right clicking on your project. Do the following things : -

- Into your build setting search for the key **Defines Module** and make it yes
- Remove all header file path from **Header Search Path** and just drag and drop your **Bridging-Header.h** file path
- After that remove derived data and import your **"ProjectName.Swift.h"** file where you want to use your swift code.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did what you told me to do and still got the same issue. 
The project it big and old so versions of configurations are old versions of Xcode configs.

Comment: I think Xcode version will not affect anything in your problem. If you need just send me your code so that i can try on that

Comment: It's a production product of the company so i can't send you the code.
Thank you for your help M.Raj

Comment: you can give me just small part of code where i can show you the integration if swift file on it , after that you can easily understand if you want then.

Comment: Thank you very much Raj Oria, actually the problem is solved it wasn't only swift Objc integration problem. it was because there was too many useless manually created umbrella headers so after the delating all useless files it start working.